# What is the max column length of TEXT field in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a text field in my Hibernate entity as shown below:

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String content;
```

So, what is the default and suggested length for this field (it is a content of a blog)? And should I set it using `length` as shown below?

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT", length = 4000)
private String content;
```

Note: My database is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max column length of text type is your RDBMS's max length for text datatype, in PostgreSQL case is 1Gb. If you want to limit size use

```
@Column (columnDefinition = "VARCHAR (n)" )
```

@Column annotation indicates specific characteristics of the physical database column, and  will be enforced by database (PostgreSQL checks and throws an error)

Or

```
@column(columndefinition="text")
```

That will adjust to the limit aforementioned, where length attribute may not work and won't be necessary.

Comment: Perfect explanations.

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) the data type `text` accepts no length limit and has a maximum size of 1GB.

If you want a constraint to limit the length, use a check constraint on a `text` column or use the `varchar(4000)`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually my purpose is not restrict, then >>> **1.** Should I use `@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")` ?

Comment: **2.** Actually I am not sure if I should use `@Lob` instead of this approach for the TEXT fields. Do you have any idea?

Comment: As I wrote: if you want to restrict the length, use `varchar(4000)`. And `@Lob` is completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot horse! But I also tried to use `@Lob` and basically it is also working. What is wrong with it? And when I should prefer and not prefer it in Hibernate?